# How to render bigger image with high resolution ? Using GLsurfaceview

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm using this code to make effect for the images 
http://grishma102.blogspot.com/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html

but my problem if I choose an image with these sizes for example ( width 4128) and ( hight 2322) 
it's giving me this error message

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 21709 java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: glError 1281
    at com.mekdev.imageaffects.GLToolbox.checkGlError(GLToolbox.java:62)
    at com.mekdev.imageaffects.TextureRender.renderTexture(TextureRender.java:95)
    at com.mekdev.imageaffects.EffectsFilterActivity.renderResult(EffectsFilterActivity.java:566)
    at com.mekdev.imageaffects.EffectsFilterActivity.onDrawFrame(EffectsFilterActivity.java:584)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

please can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should chech glError after texture loading. On large amount of mobile GPU maximun texture size is 2048x2048. Sometimes you only have to use textures with sides a power of 2(1024,2048,...). So check glError after texture loading and LogCat(on some devices easy to see whats goes wrong with GL in LogCat).  And to draw so large image use several small textures.

Comment: when i checked the logcat I found this problem 1281 is GL_INVALID_VALUE can you help me I used the same code here :http://grishma102.blogspot.com/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html

Comment: https://github.com/Grishu/ImageEffects is link from the original example. Just import it to Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're exceeding the maximum texture size for the device.  Most mobile devices have a max of 2048 or 4096.

You can query it on your device with something like:

```
int[] values = new int[1];
GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, values, 0);
// max is in values[0]
```

You can't have a texture larger than the max, so you'll either need to scale it to fit, or split it into more than one texture.

Comment: first of all thanks for reply I appreciate it. but because I'm making image effect I think it's not good to scale the image so i think it's better to use more the one texture but can you tell me how ?                  thanks for help